# How to play Audio in HTML for the iPhone? Example that does not work :(

Tags: html, ios, iphone, audio

I have used the audio-tag HTML element to try to play audio at

**Example of Audio Issue**: [www.justinreina.com/nice_try](http://justinreina.com/nice_try/index.html)

Using the following HTML

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="justinsingsbetter.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

It works fine in a Desktop Web Browser (*e.g. Firefox*) but the audio does not play on an iPhone (*iPhone 6, IOS 9.1*). Why is this not working, and does anyone have any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Safari does not support autoloading of audio.
More specifically mobile Safari ignores the following automatically:

- the `autoplay` attribute
- the `preload` attribute
- `audio.play()` in a method that runs on page load

Audio streams can only be loaded when triggered by a user touch event such as `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onclick`, or `ontouchstart`.

As of now there is no workaround to it. Before iOS 4.2.1 you were able to load an audio file from the callback of a synchronous Ajax call . This was patched in iOS 4.2.1 since the synchronous call would lock the whole browser and if an error occurred while loading the file the whole browser would remain locked and have to be force closed.

Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/

Comment: iOS does not appear to allow playing audio even *with touch* on my server... e.g., using code similar to the OP's, but with `preload="none"`, no `autoplay` set, etc.